# Inconsistent output for init process name using 'ps'

Tags: 16.04, systemd, init, ps

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, and am following allong "Starting and Stopping" services chapter of the Linux Bible (9th edition). I am trying to find what type of init daemon I have (`init` or `systemd`) which requires I find what process has PID of 1. However, I get 2 different results depending on how I run the command...

```
webmaster@my-site:~$ ps -p1
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:29 systemd
webmaster@my-site:~$ ps -F -p1
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0  9420  5336   0 Feb23 ?        00:00:29 /sbin/init
```

It says `systemd` for PID1 after running the first command, but `/sbin/init` for PID1 after running the second command.

Answer (score 2):

```
                        GRUB(GRand Unified Bootloader)
                                       |                                                          
                                       |
                                       |                                                  
                                       V
                                     Kernel
                                       |
                                Hardware check
                                       |
                            -----------------------
                            |init processes start |
                            -----------------------
                                      /|\
                                     / | \
                            SysVinit   |  systemd
                        init scripts   |
                                    Upstart
```

Let me try to explain with the *diagram* above. Now in Ubuntu it started with `SysVinit`, then `Upstart`, and finally `Systemd`. Each of these will *handle* the `init`process which *begins all* things Linux and Ubuntu in general.

Now Ubuntu is gradually moving away from `Upstart` and into `Systemd` and is the current `init` controller on Ubuntu Xenial. The `init` process starts all things (or most, as the kernel has its own process that are unrelated to `init`), but what handles or controls that `init` process is either `SysVinit`, `Upstart`, or `Systemd` depending on your version of Ubuntu. In your case it's the newer `Systemd`. But bare in mind that you will also see remnants of the old system, where commands such as `initctl`, `service` etc still play.

So to get the initial system functions or services up and running new Ubuntu now uses `systemd` the replacement for `init daemon` of old. But for backward compatibility `init` still runs in the background.

According to `man ps`, passing an `-F` flag causes the `command arguments` to be printed out. So in this case the command is seen with:

```
ps -p 1

#Result
PID TTY          TIME CMD
1 ?        00:00:02 systemd
```

Then to see the the *arguments* passed to that command:

```
ps -F -p 1

#Result
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 46414  6336   1 05:48 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init splash
```

So `ps -p 1` ==> `command`, and `ps -F -p 1` ==> `arguments passed` to it. Long story short `-F` Extra full format, seeing more information that is related to the `ps -p 1` or `systemd` command. What you see is an underlying `init` process run by `systemd` on Ubuntu Xenial. Take note of the *TIME*:00:00:02, which is the same for both `systemd` and `/sbin/init` in both forms of `ps`.

Please look at this [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) and you will see why `/sbin/init` shows up when `-F` option is used. `Systemd` runs with `PID 1 as /sbin/init`.

Source:

`man ps`

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: Interesting.  However, still confused as to why (or how) the ps command is outputting different values for the cmd column...As in, what is 'ps' doing differently between these two calls...

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 16.04, default `init` is `systemd`

```
~$ ls -l /sbin/init
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Oct  3 20:44 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

`systemd` is the one really running. `-F` option makes `ps` print the exact command line (including arguments) used to launch it.